# How to consume Facebook authentication in Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, facebook-login, social-authentication

I am trying to implement Facebook authentication in a Web API project which will be used by mobile clients as a backend. There will be no local login.

I followed the steps explained in [Microsoft's documentation](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/external-authentication-services#FACEBOOK) to create the project using Visual Studio's Web API template. I already have Facebook app Id&secret, I set OAuth redirect URI on Facebook's panel accordingly and I set the Id&secret in the Startup.Auth.cs file:

```
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(
appId: "***",
appSecret: "***");
```

Then I created a LocalDB database and set the web.config DefaultConnection string:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=webapidb;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

When I run the project, I can use **Account.GetExternalLogin** (/api/Account/ExternalLogin/?provider=Facebook) method with GET to initiate login. I am redirected to Facebook's approval page, then when I am redirected back to **GetExternalLogin**, I can see that the method's "**error**" parameter is null. I also added a watch on the **User.Identity.IsAuthenticated** and it evaluates to true inside the method.

Up to now everything is as expected.

But once **GetExternalLogin** method completes, I try to invoke any [Authenticate]-decorated method (like */api/values/3*) and I get HTTP401 Unauthorized error.

One more thing is that when I open AspNetUsers table there are no records, I was expecting to see my Facebook Id and user name saved there.

Could you please explain how the authentication mechanism should be consumed by the clients and what should be done to have the user Id and name saved to the database?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just a month ago I had your same doubt.

You should really try to decouple your resources server(API) from your Authorization/Authentication Server. Take a look into OAuth2 flows to fully grasp what I'm talking about.

I'm using [this open source project](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3), these guys gavesus the authorization server with open id for the authentication part, the only thing you have to do is to configure it to your needs.

Here are some questions that I've asked about this topic

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/115799/what-to-do-for-my-web-api-authentication-scheme

[Rest API authentication mechanism, what to do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35641974/rest-api-authentication-mechanism-what-to-do)

[Relation to users when these are stored in an external Identity provider service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36904302/relation-to-users-when-these-are-stored-in-an-external-identity-provider-service)

[How to secure my API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35516515/how-to-secure-my-api)

Also check the Pluralsight courses by Kevin Dockx, it explains very well the whole process, from creating the api, configuring identity server and how to consume the service from an MVC client